# Can "gem install" be configured to install executables outside /usr/bin/ by default?

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems

By default, when you `sudo gem install thegemname` it will install executables into `/usr/bin/`

Is there a way to change this? For example, to install them into `/usr/local/rubygems/bin` (or any other path)?

The path doesn't seem to be hard-coded into the gemspec file, so I don't see why this shouldn't be possible (although I have very little experience with Ruby/Gems)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See http://www.rubygems.org/read/chapter/11 and specify a `~/.gemrc` which defines a gemhome variable.

For example:

```
gemhome: /usr/local/rubygems
```

You can also place this file in `/etc/gemrc`

Alternatively you can set the [`GEM_HOME` env-variable](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/12):

```
$ export GEM_HOME=/tmp/gemtest
$ gem install bundler
$ ls /tmp/gemtest/bin/
bundle
```

**Update (10 years later):**

Andrey Rodionov below suggest using

```
gem: --bindir /usr/bin
```

Comment: Thanks! I hope you don't mind I updated your answer. I prodded around rubygems.rb - the bin dir is appended to gemhome, there doesn't seem any obvious way to override only this, but setting gemhome to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/ (on OS X) gives a bin path of /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bin which is perfect

Comment: Gah, not quite perfect. There is a default /usr/bin override for the Mac distribution..

Comment: Not working. New error generated ```Unable to resolve dependency: user requested 'did_you_mean (= 1.0.0)'```. Changing to ```gem: --bindir /usr/bin``` helped.

Answer (score 20):

I'm adding this as an answer so that it is obvious when I run into this problem again :)

First, move all the bins in `/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/` to `/usr/bin/`. If you don't do this, then uninstalling or updating a gem will not remove the binary from the original bin directory.

You may also wish to remove the old path from `$PATH`

Next, edit `~/.gemrc` and add (or update) the following line:

```
gem: --bindir /usr/bin
```

This overrides gem so that it always uses /usr/bin/ as the bin dir.

No need to update the path (especially messy for multiple-user machines).

Comment: Yep, this seems to work perfectly (at least on Rubygem 1.3.6)

Comment: How do you do: *You may also wish to remove the old path from $PATH*

Comment: @JohnRPerry There are several good techniques for [removing directories from the $PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11650840/41688)

Answer (score 2):

On OS X, the executable directory is overridden to `/usr/bin` in the file `/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/defaults.rb`

```
# The default directory for binaries
def self.default_bindir
  if defined? RUBY_FRAMEWORK_VERSION then # mac framework support
    '/usr/bin'
  else # generic install
    ConfigMap[:bindir]
  end
end
```

As a hackish work around, I changed `/usr/bin` to my desired bin location, which works correctly. There doesn't seem to be any way to override bindir from the `~/.gemrc` config?

Comment: This is really annoying. There is no way to change this because it depends on the global constant. And if you do change it everytime rubygems is updated you have to change it again. I'd like to shoot the guy responsible for this appalling decision.

Comment: I submitted a bug report for this: http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=27641&group_id=126&atid=575

Comment: Actually, we were wrong. You can change the bindir. I documented it here: http://wiki.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/cpan-ruby-gems-and-python-disttools

Comment: Updated wiki link that Max posted: http://wiki.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/gems-eggs-and-perl-modules

Comment: Updated link again since the wiki is gone: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Gems,-Eggs-and-Perl-Modules.md

Comment: If you remove the /Library/Ruby/Site folder, it'll default to the implementation in /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems. There the folder set to /usr/local/bin. I suspect the Site folder in /Library/Ruby is a leftover from a previous Version of OSX

Answer (score 1):

To install the executable to a desired directory, the command line option `--bindir` may be used:

```
sudo gem install thegemname --bindir /usr/local/rubygems/bin
```

Tried this option successfully with gem version 2.0.14.1. 
For more command line options, run `gem install --help` on the command line.