# How to replace placeholder character or word in variable with value from another variable in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, replace

I'm trying to write a simple Bash script. I have a simple "template" variable:

```
template = "my*appserver"
```

I then have a function (`get_env()`) that returns the values `dev`, `qa`, or `live`. I'd like to call `get_env` and then string-replace the `template` variable with `get_env`'s return value and swap it out with the asterisk. So:

```
# Returns "dev"
server = get_env

# Prints "mydevappserver"
template = string_replace(server, template)
```

Or:

```
# This time, it returns "live"
server = get_env

# Prints "myliveappserver"
template = string_replace(server, template)
```

What should I be using in lieu of this `string_replace()` function to accomplish the binding?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Bash can do string replacement by itself:

```
template='my*appserver'
server='live'
template="${template/\*/$server}"
```

See the [advanced bash scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) for more details on string replacement.

So for a bash function:

```
function string_replace {
    echo "${1/\*/$2}"
}
```

And to use:

```
template=$(string_replace "$template" "$server")
```

Comment: This (`"${1/\*/$2}"`)only replace the first occurence in a script:(

Comment: The solution is rather simple, the correct form to replace ALL occurence is `"${1//\*/$2}"`

Comment: Readers should be hesitant about links to the ABS. In places, it is a very useful resource, but it has content and presentation issues.

Answer (score 41):

String replacement in a bash-script can e.g. be achieved by sed:

```
template=$(echo $template | sed 's/old_string/new_string/g')
```

This will replace old_string with new_string in the template variable.

Comment: If I want to replace a lot, the number of `sed` invocations will surely impact the performance of my script.

Answer (score 8):

As nobody mentioned it, here's a cool possibility using `printf`. The place-holder must be `%s` though, and not `*`.

```
# use %s as the place-holder
template="my%sappserver"

# replace the place-holder by 'whatever-you-like':
server="whatever-you-like"
printf -v template "$template" "$server"
```

Done!

If you want a function to do that (and notice how all the other solutions mentioning a function use an ugly subshell):

```
#!/bin/bash

# This wonderful function should be called thus:
# string_replace "replacement string" "$placeholder_string" variable_name
string_replace() {
    printf -v $3 "$2" "$1"
}

# How to use it:
template="my%sappserver"
server="whatever-you-like"

string_replace "$server" "$template" destination_variable

echo "$destination_variable"
```

Done (again)!

Hope you enjoyed it... now, adapt it to your needs!

**Remark.** It seems that this method using `printf` is slightly faster than bash's string substitution. And there's no subshell at all here! Wow, that's the best method in the West.

**Funny.** If you like funny stuff you could write the function `string_replace` above as

```
string_replace() {
    printf -v "$@"
}

# but then, use as:
string_replace destination_variable "$template" "$server"
```

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, either 'sed' as the others have said, or start with your template in 2 separate variables and construct on the fly. e.g.

```
templateprefix="my"
templatesuffix="appserver"

server=get_env

template=${templateprefix}${server}${templatesuffix}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on `@Spencer Rathbun` response, this can also be done this way:

```
   function string_replace {
        #DOC: "${string/match/replace}"
        string=$1
        echo "${string/$2/$3}"
    }

    template='my__patternReplacing__appserver'
    match='__patternReplacing__'
    replace='live'

    template=$(string_replace "$template" "$match" "$replace")
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do something like this, but I needed sed and the replace clause needed to include a variable. I ended up with this.

Where the variable name is $puttyline

```
sed "s/\(\[remote .origin.\]\)/\1\n$puttyline/"
```

So sed searches for `[remote "origin"]` and remembers the match, and inserts a line right after, containing whatever's in the variable `$puttyline`.

This can get ugly however if $puttyline contains any special characters that sed would react to, like \ or $. You have to either escape them prior with another call to sed, or... do something smarter in bash that I'm too crappy with bash to know. For example, to double-escape all backslashes:

```
sed 's/\\/\\\\/g'
```

Comment: won't there be encoding issues if $puttline contains special characters?

Comment: @FrankSchwieterman That really depends more on whether your input encoding matches your output, than how this solution functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bash script that wraps this up

#### Example:

```
$ search_and_replace.sh "test me out" "test me" ez
ez out
```

#### search_and_replace.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
function show_help()
{
  echo ""
  echo "usage: SUBJECT SEARCH_FOR REPLACE_WITH"
  echo ""
  echo "e.g. "
  echo ""
  echo "test t a                     => aesa"
  echo "'test me out' 'test me' ez   => ez out"
  echo ""

  exit
}

if [ "$1" == "help" ]
then
  show_help
  exit
fi
if [ -z "$3" ]
then
  show_help
  exit
fi

SUBJECT=$1
SEARCH_FOR=$2
REPLACE_WITH=$3

echo "$SUBJECT" | sed -e "s/$SEARCH_FOR/$REPLACE_WITH/g"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many posts available online but the one which worked fine for me is as below.

There are 2 ways to achieve this, if you want to replace a string (my old string is with special character :) with another string in a file, then use this:

```
sed -i '/oldtext:/c\newtext: Rahul'  ./printName.txt
```

Secondly, if you want to search for a string and then replace it with your variable, then do this:

```
#here im concatinating two key + value(myvariable).
firstkey="oldtext: old"

key="newtext: "

value=$(cat ./variableStoredHere.txt)

key+=$value
```

result for below command will be oldtext: old

```
echo $firstkey
```

result for below command will be will be newtext: Rahul

```
echo $key 


sed -i "s/$firstkey/$key/g" ./printName.txt
```