# remove entries from PATH while uninstalling rpm

Tags: linux, bash, rpm, rpm-spec

To leave the system in a cleaner state, I am trying to remove entries from the PATH in the %preun section of my rpm spec file.

I found couple of threads on stackoverflow that I tried

[What is the most elegant way to remove a path from the $PATH variable in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370047/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-to-remove-a-path-from-the-path-variable-in-bash)
AND
[Linux: Remove path from $PATH variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650840/linux-remove-path-from-path-variable)

Answers in both these links work perfectly when I manually run them on a terminal.
But, they don't work when I run the rpm -e xx command. 
If my PATH looked like this after successful installation:

```
    /usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/lpp/mmfs/bin
```

and I am trying to remove /usr/lpp/mmfs/bin,

After the rpm uninstall the PATH looks like:

```
    /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
```

**Questions:**
1) Do I need to do something different when the commands mentioned in the earlier links are run from the spec file?

2) What are some recommended ways to remove PATH entries during rpm uninstalls?

**Note**
Commands I have tried in spec file are:

```
PATH=$(echo $PATH | sed -e 's;:\?/home/user/bin;;' -e 's;/home/user/bin:\?;;')
```

and

```
PATH=${PATH/:\/home\/user\/bin/}
```

Comment: Better to use: `PATH=$(echo $PATH | sed -e 's;/home/user/bin;;' -e 's;::;:;')`

Comment: There is usually no reson for an RPM package to install binaries outside the standard system PATH in the first place.

Comment: Certainly not binaries that a normal user needs to run on their own such that modifying `$PATH` is a good idea. In fact, modifying the system or a user's `$PATH` via an RPM is almost always the wrong thing to do (except in very specific/controlled deployment scenarios).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RPM `%preun` script **cannot** affect the `PATH` variable of any running shells. That isn't possible.

It can't (directly) affect the `PATH` variable of any new shells either.

The only thing it can do is remove whatever changes it made to the system (or user *shudder*) shell startup files that caused the `PATH` variable additions to be made.

Removing those changes will cause any new shells not to have those changes made and therefore not to have those additional `PATH` entries in them.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and answer. So, Etan, what you are suggesting is I try to modify the .bashrc or similar file / remove changes in it that were done during install.

Comment: If your RPM made any such `$PATH` modifications during install then yes, removing them would be potentially appropriate. Though, as I just said in a comment on the OP, an RPM that modifies `$PATH` is a bad idea as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way of adding to a `PATH` (and subsequently, removing it later), would be to drop a file `yourpackage.sh` and `yourpackage.csh` in `/etc/profile.d`.

I also agree with others that it's probably a bad idea, but if you *need* to do it, that's how I would.