# UAAC command line-utility not work

Tags: ruby, rubygems, predix

We are working on Predix Mobile SDK.So we are try to set Predix Mobile Development Environment for that we need set `UAAC command line-utility` .We flowed this link (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-uaac).
For Install we tried like this

```
gem install cf-uaac
```

We got error this

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.
```

after that we google about this error but we got nothing .Please guide to us for UAAC CLI.

Answer (score 0):

The cloud foundry [cf-uaac](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-uaac) cli tool is written in Ruby, so installation is done with `gem`, the ruby package manager.

You can run `gem env` from a terminal to find the installation directory for gems which is probably `/usr/bin` in your case.  You wouldn't want to install your gems there as only root has permission to write.  If you are on OSX there may even be [more to the story](http://www.hacksparrow.com/os-x-el-capitan-screwed-up-ruby-gems-and-how-to-fix-it.html).

I'm not sure what OS you are using so can't be too prescriptive, but a few suggestions for you can be found in this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333508/can-gem-install-be-configured-to-install-executables-outside-usr-bin-by-defa) to override this default behavior on your system:

- Override install location on the commandline `--user-install cf-uaac`
- Edit your `~/.gemrc` to include something like this or change to one of the **GEM PATHS**
- Re-install ruby to a different location where you do have write permission
- Use ruby version manager `rvm` if you will be doing lots of ruby dev work and want to switch versions / gems

You can find out lots more about the install command in the [rubygems guide](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-install) if you were interested in learning more.

Hope that gets you going again.

Comment: thanks for reply .now we got other issue.
Anshuls-Mac-mini-2:~ pankajthakur$ gem install cf-uaac
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cf-uaac' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from http://rubygems.org/ - no such name (http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Please guide to us.

Comment: This should probably be asked as a separate question, but that appears like the site is blocked. You may be behind a firewall and need to use a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

UAAC is the Ruby-based command line interface (CLI) for interacting with the Cloud Foundry User Account and Authentication (UAA)

first install Ruby, you can follow the guidelines (steps 1 & 2) from here:

[Ruby for Windows](https://forwardhq.com/help/installing-ruby-windows)

then run this commend from powershell:

```
gem install cf-uaac
```

If you are behind a proxy you should add the source:

```
gem sources -a http://rubygems.org
```