# How to permanently fix "don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory"

Tags: macos, installation, terminal, permissions, rubygems

This all started by attempting to install `cocoapods`through the terminal. Long story short, I kept getting an error that my `rubygems` version was not acceptable. I then attempted to update that version but kept getting the error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.
```

I found a solution that worked: `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin rubygems-update`

The issue is that now EVERY time I install anything via terminal, I have to use `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin`. Which I do not remember ever being the case (but I may be incorrect). Is there a solution to negate having to enter in that full line every time I install something via terminal? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333508/can-gem-install-be-configured-to-install-executables-outside-usr-bin-by-defa/2679036

Comment: Is there a solution?  I am facing the same issue.